# OpenTok Screenshare - View full screen on subscriber side

Tags: opentok

I am using OpenTok v2.14.0.0, for screen share. Streaming etc are working seamlessly. The only problem is, on the subscriber side, I am not able to see the complete Publisher's screen. On resizing the subscriber window (in which the streaming is happening), the video inside stretches maintaining the aspect ratio.
I have tried changing my WPF UI element control to `Grid` and `UniformGrid`, but did not work. Hence, I believe this has something to do with my subscriber's configurations. On js side, there is a property fitMode, I am looking for a similar setting on windows side.

[Here is the video](https://hub.mangoapps.com/sf/MTY3NTc5XzE3MzI0ODY) where one can see that the publisher (he is publishing his chrome window), gets stretched outside the bounds.

xaml control:

```
<Grid x:Name="SubscriberGrid"/>
```

when I receive the stream:

```
var uiElement = ((UIElement)subscriber.VideoRenderer);                       
SubscriberGrid.Children.Add(uiElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and for me it was because I had set the fitMode property to 'cover' instead of 'contain'.  Changing fitMode to 'contain' fixed the issue:

```
var subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscribers', {
            insertMode: 'append',
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            fitMode: "contain"
        }, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.error('Failed to subscribe', error);
            }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you @jeff.. The solution you provided is for web. I am using opentok.dll which is in windows desktop application development domain. This solution works correctly for web applications. Such property does not exist in opentok.dll provided for Windows.